# How to run python programs (written with Enthought Canopy) without opening the editor?

Tags: python, macos, canopy

I would like to be able to open a simple program I have written with the editor Canopy (from Enthought) without opening the editor itself, only with a double click on something.

I work on a mac.

I tried to go with: right-click + get info + open with... + "python launcher". But it doesn't work. I don't know if it is because my program uses Canopy specific packages like Traits and TraitsUi.
Thanks a lot for any help!
Bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should use the terminal

```
$python yourpgrogram.py
```

If you really need to double-click try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to make a bundled app.

Comment: Yeah... i just saw that i wrote a stupid question. I edit it now. I wanted to say: open with a simple double-click. Without opnening anything else XD
Thanks  anyway!

Comment: Make an app with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), when you make a bundled one it should work just like a normal OSX app.